# What is the correct Solr fieldType to use for sorting integer values?

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene

I am using Solr 3.6.1. What is the correct field type to use for a Solr sort field containing integer values? I need this field only for sorting and will never do range queries on it. Should I use `integer` or `sint`?

I see that in schema.xml, there is `sint` type declared as:

```
 <!-- Numeric field types that manipulate the value into
         a string value that isn't human-readable in its internal form,
         but with a lexicographic ordering the same as the numeric ordering,
         so that range queries work correctly. -->
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

whereas `integer` says the following:

```
 <!-- numeric field types that store and index the text
         value verbatim (and hence don't support range queries, since the
         lexicographic ordering isn't equal to the numeric ordering) -->
    <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
```

The main reason I am asking this is because every Solr sort I do on an `sint` field (I have lots of them declared as dynamic fields) populates the (unconfigurable) lucene fieldCache. I see on the stats page (http://HOST:PORT/solr/CORE/admin/stats.jsp) under fieldCache that `sint` sorts are stored as

`org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCache$StringIndex`

whereas `integer` sorts are stored as

`org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCache.DEFAULT_INT_PARSER`

which I believe consumes less space?

---

UPDATE: Solr 3.6.1 schema.xml has `int` declared as `TrieIntField` i.e. as

`<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>`

The one above was from an older solr version.

Comment: You should always use TrieIntField instead of IntField and SortableIntField: this class has a **much** more memory-efficient FieldCache impl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need range queries, use "integer" as  [Sorts work correctly on both](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/sint-vs-integer-td495185.html)

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign) :-

> Sortable FieldTypes like sint, sdouble are a bit of a misnomer. They
>   are not needed for Sorting in the sense described above, but are
>   needed when doing RangeQuery queries. Sortables, in fact, refer to the
>   notion of making the number sort correctly lexicographically as
>   Strings. That is, if this is not done, the numbers 1..10 sort
>   lexicographically as 1,10, 2, 3... Using an sint, however remedies
>   this. If, however, you don't need to do RangeQuery queries and only
>   need to sort on the field, then just use an int or double or the
>   equivalent appropriate class. You will save yourself time and memory.

Answer (score 1):

The Sortable field types are being deprecated in Solr 5 and should not be used. You can use the solr int or tint field types