# Solr sort does not seem to work

Tags: solr

I have been searching this a lot, but everything I do, does not seem to work, I tried,

```
cat: wolf; category desc
cat: wolf; sort category desc
$query->setQuery("cat: wolf")->sort("category desc");
```

I cannot sort the results, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: whats the fieldtype config for category ??

Comment: <field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>, I have to sort it,from a-z or z-a, and other fields from 1-9 and 9-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorting doesn't work well on multivalued and tokenized fields.

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort)

> Sorting can be done on the "score" of the document, or on any multiValued="false" indexed="true" field provided that field is either non-tokenized (ie: has no Analyzer) or uses an Analyzer that only produces a single Term (ie: uses the KeywordTokenizer)

Use string as the field type (or KeywordTokenizer with lowercase filters and ascii filters applied) and copy the category field into the new field.

```
<field name="category_sort" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

<copyField source="category" dest="category_sort" />
```

Comment: why do we need copyfields ?

Comment: Copyfields can be used for Multiple reasons e.g. to Club multiple fields to one field, Creating multiple copies of single field with different analysis etc ..

Comment: <field name="point" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />, this is my point field, there are values from 1 to 10, I use this query, cat: wolf; point desc, but this one does not seem to work too, what should I do ? thank you for your help :)

Comment: this should work fine as int can provide a normal sorting behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372323/what-is-the-correct-solr-fieldtype-to-use-for-sorting-integer-values/13372761

Comment: I now I am wasting your time I am sorry, this is my last question, http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&sort=point+desc, when I send it from url, it works, I guess my query is wrong, this is my query,    $query->setQuery("cat: wolf; point asc"); what is the right query ? can you help me ?

Comment: what client are you using ?? maybe sort needs to be passed in a different way. This is not related to Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i also face same issue in solr V 8.6.1

```
<fieldType name="lowercase2" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <field name="top_cat_en_US" type="lowercase2" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```